# Log4J File lock

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, log4j

I had used Log4J in my application, but I have another application want to read the log file of Log4J .Is there any thead-safe issue in this situation? thanks.

Comment: You mean Log4j file is in use by some other/or same app and you want to read it? What for? What is your scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no thread-safety issues with reading a Log4j file.

You've got no way of knowing when Log4j is going to write more data to it, but that isn't a thread safety issue.